# Getting error while uninstalling java from command line wmic product where "name like 'Java%'" call uninstall?

Tags: cmd

when i am running command `wmic product where "name like 'Java%'" call uninstall`to uninstall java it is killing all java.exe's but showing error at last.

```
`C:\Users\m1024193\Desktop>wmic product where "name like 'Java%'" call uninstall
Executing (\\B3MD18600\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber="{26A24AE4-039
D-4CA4-87B4-2F83216029FF}",Name="Java(TM) 6 Update 29",Version="6.0.290")->Unins
tall()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 0;
};

ERROR:
Description = Generic failure`
```

Comment: ERROR:
Description = Generic failure`

Comment: Generic failure what does this error means ?why i am getting this.